# Cycling through a list starting at index of variable

Tags: python

Is there a one-liner that could replace the try and except in this code?

Find variable in list then return the next index or the first if the index is out of range.

```
def cycle_my_list(my_var):
    my_list = ['cleaner', 'list', 'cycle']
    try:
        return my_list[my_list.index(my_var) + 1]
    except IndexError:
        return my_list[0]
```

Expected result:

```
>>> cycle_my_list('list')
'cycle'
>>> cycle_my_list('cycle')
'cleaner'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the modulo `%` operator

```
my_list = ['cleaner', 'list', 'cycle']
return my_list[(my_list.index(my_var) + 1) % len(my_list)]
```

Comment: this will crash with error if not in list ... read the OP - it will return the 0 index even if not in list

Comment: no it won't -- `my_list.index(my_var)` is always an `int`

Comment: `print(my_list[(my_list.index("tata") + 1) % len(my_list)])` => `ValueError: 'tata' is not in list`

Comment: @PatrickArtner Oh I see. Except OP is not trying to protect against bad inputs. They're just trying to cycle correct ones. -- sneaky edit btw.

Comment: My fault - he guards only agaisnt  IndexError -  maybe I should read the OP again ;)

Comment: @PatrickArtner Exactly, OPs will throw `ValueError` (nb not `IndexError`) as well.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Help me out here, what's the second?

Comment: In my case `my_var` will always be in the list so this answer works

Answer (score 2):

This will work for both whether the item is in the list or not and it's a one-liner too!

```
return my_list[my_list.index(my_var) + 1] if my_var in my_list and my_list.index(my_var)+1<len(my_list) else my_list[0]
```

Update :This might be more readable as Sasha Tsukanov suggested:

```
return my_list[(my_list.index(my_var) + 1) % 3] if my_var in my_list else my_list[0]
```

Comment: Maybe it is more readable to combine the `in` checking with the modulus operator trick? Thus, we could exclude this long thing: `my_list.index(my_var)+1<len(my_list)`

Comment: Will you please give me an example?

Comment: Like so:
`return my_list[(my_list.index(my_var) + 1) % len(my_list)] if my_var in my_list else my_list[0]`

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer as your suggestion.